# Change the default temporary folder with KNP Snappy Bundle

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using KNPLabs' KnpSnappy bundle with `wkhtmltopdf` HTML-to-PDF generator to pipe a Twig-generated HTML file to the PDF generator, and I want to change the default temp folder where the HTML and PDF files are created. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: The `knp_snappy:` section of `config.yml` supports a `temporary_folder` key-value pair, like so:

```
knp_snappy:
    temporary_folder: "C:\your\custom\temp\path"
```